# What precisely is an expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider whether `x` in the declaration `int x;` is an expression.

I used to think that it's certainly not, but the grammar calls the variable name an *[`id-expression`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl.general#nt:declarator-id)* here.

One could then argue that only [*`expression`*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma#nt:expression) is an expression, not *`??-expression`*. But then in `1 + 2`, neither `1` nor `2` match, because those are *`additive-expression`* and *`multiplicative-expression`* respectively, not *`expression`*s. But common sense says those should be called expressions too.

We could decide that any *`??-expression`* (including *`expression`*) is an expression, but then the variable name in a declaration matches as well.

We could define an expression to be any *`??-expression`* except *`id-expression`*, but this feels rather arbitrary.

What's the right grammatical definition of an expression, and is the variable name in its declaration an expression or not?

Comment: Unsure if `language-lawyer` is appropriate or not. I'm looking for a sane but precise definition that that I can teach others, but I don't want to end up with "`1` and `2` in `1 + 2` are not actually expressions", because it contradicts common sense.

Comment: The grammar is an hierarchy of notions. Any id-expression is an expression, but not any expression is an id-expression. Any additive-expression is also an expression, but not any expression is an additive-expression.

Comment: What is the problem of `id-expression` being an expression? As the linked page says, it is a restricted form of `primary-expression`. So the "expression" in a declaration has to be this very specific type of expression.

Comment: @nielsen It brings some confusing questions. If it's an expression, does it have a value category? (in its own declaration) A type?

Comment: @n.m. I would argue that a [grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) is a set of expansion rules, plus a starting term. *"Any additive-expression is also an expression"* I don't think so. Yes, *`expression`* can in some cases expand to *`additive-expression`*, but this expansion doesn't happen for `1` in the case of `1 + 2`, because the lhs of `+` is directly an *`additive-expression`*.

Comment: The grammar can be interpreted as a set of expansion rules, a set of contraction rules, or a set of definitions. If we want to answer questions like "is an id-expression an expression", we interpret it as a set of definitions. If we interpret the grammar as a set of rules, then such questions make no sense. 'Expression' (not "an" expression) is a unique symbol in the set of rules, nothing more.

Comment: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2876#issuecomment-575207420 https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2876#issuecomment-575804663

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the links provided by @LanguageLawyer ([1](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2876#issuecomment-575207420), [2](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2876#issuecomment-575804663)), I'm convinced the consensus is that *`id-expression`* is a misnomer, and not always an expression (e.g. it's not an expression in a declaration).

Then, a source substring is an expression if at least one of its parents in the parse tree is called:

- *`expression`*, **or**
- *`*-expression`*<sup>1</sup> but not *`id-expression`*

, and that parent expands exactly to this substring and nothing more.

This is the same definition @n.m. proposed, except I allow *"`*-expression`* and not *`id-expression`"* nodes as well.

---

<sup>1</sup> `*` is a wildcard for any string.

Comment: I would say that it is an expression if it is an id-expression, as long as it is not a declarator.  id-expressions "in isolation" are ambiguous -- they might be expressions or declarators, depending on context.

Comment: @ChrisDodd This definition doesn't reject *all* *`id-expressions`* (it allows those that are also some other *`*-expression`* s).

Comment: _at least one of its parents in the parse tree is called: `expression`_ This makes `id-expression` in the RHS of a class member access an expression.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The *"and that parent expands exactly to this substring and nothing more"* part should exclude that, I think.

Answer (score 3):

What does the question "is `x` an expression" mean?

When we talk about specific occurrences of expressions and identifiers in a specific program, we must consider its parse tree. A substring of a program is an `expression` if some occurrence of `expression` node in its parse tree expands to that substring.

Thus, `x` in the declaration `int x;` is not an expression because there is no `expression` in the parse tree (of any valid program that contains `int x;` as a declaration) that expands to this occurrence of `x`. There is an `id-expression` node, but that particular `id-expression` is not an expansion of an `expression` node, it is a part of an expansion of a `declaration` node.

When talking about about expressions and identifiers in isolation, then "is a" means "expands to/contracts to, according to some rule in the grammar". Thus, taken in isolation, `x` is an expression. This means we can construct a program where `x` is an expression according to the definition above.

These definitions are purely syntactic and as such are valid for any language and grammar production. However the C++ standard states informally that

> An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies a computation

and in several places talks about subexpressions as expressions on their own right. Thus the term "expression" in the standard does not coincide with the grammar element `expression`.

This is not an insurmountable problem however. The grammar is only a tool. The standard could have defined the grammar differently:

```
expression:
    expression = expression
    expression + expression
    expression * expression
    ...
    ( expression )
    id-expression
```

and resolve the ambiguities in English text. If we want the notion of expression to correspond closely to the grammar element, we probably should mentally consider the grammar presented this way.

Alternatively, as you suggest, we can consider an expansion of any `??-expression` an "expression", but replace certain occurrences of `id-expression` with a new symbol. The two approaches seem equivalent.

*Note: this version of the answer is a complete rewrite. The previous version was a result of a misunderstanding.*

Comment: I'm convinced that this is not how things work. I'll try to find a more glaring example...

Comment: Ok, consider this: in `int x;`, `x` is (among other things) an [*`identifier`*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#nt:unqualified-id). But there's also a rule [*`namespace-name -> identifier`*](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.def.general#nt:namespace-name). By applying your logic, `x` in `int x;` (or any identitifer anywhere) is a namespace name (solely because such rule exists, even though it's not used here). This is exactly the same as saying that any *`additive-expression`* is an *`expression`*, because the *`expression -> additive-expression`* rule exists.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see what you mean, let me amend my answer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I ended up rewriting it completely.

Comment: Aha, so you opted for the "only *`expression`* is expression" option. But then, in `1 + 2`, neither `1` nor `2` are expressions.