# Why are curly braces {} NOT considered an operator in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, grammar

I've checked official operator list, but didn't see `{}` appear in any list of operator (either redefinable or non-redefinable).

As far as I know, `{}` is used to specify a block of code, and also used to create a *braced-init-list*, but why is NOT considered an operator in C++?

Comment: an operator operates on a thing.  `{}` doesn't do an operation, its just for syntax.

Comment: Let us invert the question. *Why would it be considered an operator*, in your opinion?

Comment: @Fureeish perhaps it does some secret operation like a function? :D

Comment: Do you have a problem that you're trying to solve? @Crackie?

Comment: what are the operands?

Comment: @sleepystar96 i have thought to overload the operator {} to create an braced-initializer-list myself :D

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai yeah, but { element1, element2...} in initializer-list, none of them is operands ?

Comment: @Crackie I'm a little certain, you just need to overload the initializer of your list class then: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: If you want your type to support an initializer list then you add a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list`

Comment: Yes, agree with @NathanOliver - see the example in the cppref link I posted: `Q(std::initializer_list<Q>) {}`

Comment: @sleepystar96 that's exactly what I have been searching for years! thanks there , best wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses of `{}`, and uses of operators like `+`, `!`, `()`, etc. are *expressions*. Specifically, the language grammar contains the rule (among many others related to expressions):

> *[postfix-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.general#nt:postfix-expression)*:
>     [postfix-expression](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.general#nt:postfix-expression) `(` *[expression-list](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.general#nt:expression-list)*<sub>opt</sub> `)`
>     *[simple-type-specifier](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#nt:simple-type-specifier)   [braced-init-list](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#nt:braced-init-list)*
>     [...]

- [[expr.post.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post.general)

The first rule matches function calls with `()` (call operator) such as `foo(0)`. The second rule matches list initialization with a given type, such as `int{0}`.

`{}` and `()` are quite similar gramatically, and it's not far from the truth to think of *braced-init-list* as an operator too. However, there are two features that distinguish operators:

1. Operators are usually composable, meaning that you can form expressions like `x() + y()`, `(&x)()`, and `x[0]()`. By comparison, *braced-init-lists* can only be applied to the name of the type, to do initialization. `{}` cannot be applied to another expression.
2. Operators are (with some exceptions) overloadable. List initialization is either performing some built-in initialization, or it calls a constructor. It is not overloadable using `operator{}`, as one would expect from an operator.

Comment: While `int{0}` is an expression, [I'd argue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74436806/2752075), the `{...}` part itself is not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I agree, I just didn't formulate it properly. Fixed it now.