# What does function type T mean?

Tags: c++

I've read this from cppreference.com:

> Function-to-pointer conversion:
> An lvalue of function type T can be implicitly converted to a prvalue pointer to that function. This does not apply to non-static member functions because lvalues that refer to non-static member functions do not exist.

Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

What does 'function type T' here mean? does that mean a function with a return type T?

Comment: No, T stands for the entire function signature (arguments and return type)

Comment: @AlanBirtles it seems to be defined in separate context, in Function-to-pointer conversion section.

Comment: @Botje i don't quite understand that, like argument and return turn type are of the same type T? or T is the combination of argument type (T1) and return type (T2)? :>

Comment: @KamilCuk that section is the exact answer to my question :> . thanks for your help everybody

Comment: A small relevant question, what is "a prvalue pointer" means in the context? :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In programming languages like C++, a function type describes the signature of a function. Specifically, it tells you what type of arguments the function takes and what type of value it returns, i.e. it is signature of that function.

The `T` serves to just give a name to that function type.

Think of

> There always exist real number `X` that is between any given distinct real numbers.

`X` is that existing real number.

For your specific example:

In C++, an lvalue of function type can indeed be implicitly converted to a prvalue (pure rvalue) pointer to that function. Here's a simple example to demonstrate this concept.

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int x) {
  std::cout << "Value of x: " << x << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  // Both of these are valid:
  void (*funcPtr1)(int) = &foo;  // Explicitly using the address-of operator
  void (*funcPtr2)(int) = foo;   // Implicit conversion to pointer - What yours example is about

  // Calling the function using the function pointers
  funcPtr1(42);  // Output: "Value of x: 42"
  funcPtr2(43);  // Output: "Value of x: 43"

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pavelka, by the way what is "a prvalue pointer" means? :> ,like an expression that denotes "an address of an entity" ?

Comment: lvalue is something on left side of assignment, you can say it is something that represents place in memoty dedicated to storing stuff, e.g. variable name. rvalue is something that can be assigned to lvalue. pr is pure r value, it means intermeddiate result to be stored somewhere. Check https://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/value_categories.html

Answer (score 3):

"of function type T" means "of any possible function type; we'll call such type `T`".

I don't see `T` being used anywhere else below (without being redefined as something else), so this looks like a minor editoral error to me.

Comment: @ HolyBlackCat , what is "a prvalue pointer" means? :>

Comment: @LiDaCute "An expression of pointer type that is a prvalue" (the expression is a prvalue, not its type). An [expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74436806/2752075) is a part of the program source (as opposed to something that exists in memory when the program runs), it means one or more operands connected with operators, or just a lone operand. Each expression has a "value category", either "prvalue", "xvalue", or "lvalue". A "prvalue" means this expression refers to an object it just created, as opposed to some old existing object.

Comment: I don't see how this is a wording error. Saying "of type `T`" where `T` is defined by its first appearance is a common wording idiom in the standard. First defining "let `T` be a function type" would be quite verbose. Reading the relevant section in the standard (https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.func#1), it's quite unambiguous, and i don't think that `T` being inline-defined causes any confusion for the reader.

Comment: The corresponding wording on cppreference is still dubious, because `T` is inline-defined, but never used, so it doesn't really need to be there.

Comment: @JanSchultke Yep, I was talking about cppreference.

Comment: Anyhow, bridge under the water; I've edited the cppreference page so that it no longer contains `T` in that sentence.

Answer (score -3):

In C++, the Notation T represents a template type parameter. It is a placeholder for a datatype that can be specified when you are creating or using a template.
Template allows you to write code that can work with different data types without duplicating code for each type.